# Starting vncserver using supervisord inside a Linux container

Tags: vnc, supervisord, docker, lxc

I'm trying to start vncserver using supervisord at the bootup time for the lxc container (I don't think being a container is relevant). The issue is that the machine starts as root. My supervisord program section looks like:

```
[program:vnc]
directory=/
user=ubuntu
environment=HOME="/home/ubuntu",USER="ubuntu"
priority=901
command=/usr/bin/vncserver -fg -geometry 1024x768 :1
```

However, I find that the log files show its trying to create a password, though there already exists a password in /home/ubuntu/.vnc/passwd

Wondering if I am missing something? Isn't user supposed to change the user, $HOME and $USER before running the command?

Comment: Can you post a Dockerfile showing how to reproduce the issue? (As a gist, pastebin, or something similar, maybe? Gist are the best because you can add a dummy passwd file...)

Answer (score 0):

You can define to run a container with specific user's name (if existing) or UID without any existing user in the image/container.

Docker documentation: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#user

> USER
>
> root (id = 0) is the default user within a container. The image
>   developer can create additional users. Those users are accessible by
>   name. When passing a numeric ID, the user does not have to exist in
>   the container.
>
> The developer can set a default user to run the first process with the
>   Dockerfile USER instruction. When starting a container, the operator
>   can override the USER instruction by passing the -u option.
>
> ```
> -u="": Username or UID
> ```
>
> Note: if you pass a numeric uid, it must be in the range of
>   0-2147483647.